# C# JSON Parse gives error 'System.ArgumentNullException' when parsing JSON array

Tags: c#, arrays, json

I'm trying to parse this JSON:

```
{"error":[],"result":{"XETHXXBT":{"a":["0.023769","64","64.000"],"b":["0.023756","42","42.000"],"c":["0.023756","1.21518360"],"v":["74038.22109284","130984.00945101"],"p":["0.023689","0.006974"],"t":[1272,2332],"l":["0.023440","0.023440"],"h":["0.024091","0.024669"],"o":"0.024084"}}}
```

The piece of data I want to get is

```
"c":["0.023756","1.21518360"],
```

More to the point, the first value of "c". The code I am using is:

```
    JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(json);
    double balance = (double)jObject["c"];
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I just get the first value of the "c" array?

Thanks!

Here is the full error report: http://pastebin.com/4S204aUG

Comment: It seems the value passed to the `JObject.Parse()` method is `null`. Are you sure the `json` variable is populated?

Comment: looks like your `jObject` is null

Comment: The `c` value is a string, not a double.  You can't convert it like that.  That's not going to fix your issue, but it's another one.

Comment: @MarkusSafar No, the json variable definitely contains the correct value.

Comment: That's interessting because as I interpreted it, that's what the stacktrace and the details of the exception tell us ;-)

Comment: @Rahul the jObject is definitely populated

Comment: @deltree Yeah. when I set it to string (which is, as you said, what it should be) the balance is null.

Comment: ok but according to you json it should be something like `result.c` and then the index of the element because `c` is an array of strings. So something like `result.CETHXXBT.c[0]` for example.

Comment: And you can use `dynamic` and the intermediate window which would make things easier for testing here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get to `c` do the following:

```
var o = JObject.Parse(<yourjsontext>);
var result = o["result"];
var XETHXXBT = result["XETHXXBT"];
var c = XETHXXBT["c"];

var value1 = (double) c[0];
var value2 = (double) c[1];
```

Comment: Will this work? It looks like the incoming object is a string.

Comment: Yes, JSON is serialized to string and deserialized from string. Try it, i just verified it works.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that your object is more complicated than it looks.

The answer is `jObject['results']['XETHXXBT']['c'][0]` or `jObject['results']['XETHXXBT']['c'][1]`.  Take a look at it with a prettifier.

```
{
   "error":[

   ],
   "result":{
      "XETHXXBT":{
         "a":[
            "0.023769",
            "64",
            "64.000"
         ],
         "b":[
            "0.023756",
            "42",
            "42.000"
         ],
         "c":[
            "0.023756",
            "1.21518360"
         ],
         "v":[
            "74038.22109284",
            "130984.00945101"
         ],
         "p":[
            "0.023689",
            "0.006974"
         ],
         "t":[
            1272,
            2332
         ],
         "l":[
            "0.023440",
            "0.023440"
         ],
         "h":[
            "0.024091",
            "0.024669"
         ],
         "o":"0.024084"
      }
   }
}
```

As you can see, your base object does not have a `c` property, so naturally it is throwing an error when you attempt to access (and automatically type cast) that nonexistent property.

Answer (score 0):

Use Like that it will give you more flexibility to get  the data , if you don't know how may level depth you have to search it will become very difficult and code will be look like tightly coupled or hardcoded whenever you working with json or xml follow class structure it will help to debug or understand the structure as well

```
public class Test {
  public string[] error { get; set; }
  public string result { get; set; }
}
  
public class Result {
   public List<Values> XETHXXBT { get; set; }
}
  
public class Values {
  public List<Double> a { get; set; }
  public List<Double> b { get; set; }
  public List<Double> c { get; set; }
}
```

After that class `Jsonconvert.deserializeObject<Test>(jsonString);` and store it in object you will proper json data in object and after that you can traaverse and get desired data according to your need.Hope it will help you T
Thanks